# How to display the multiple marker on google map

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I have code for Google Maps where I take co-ordinates from a database and display places on a map. Noww I want to set multiple markers for respective places. How can I do that? My code is as follow for the map

```
function loadGmap(lat,lang) {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var point;
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("Gmap"));
        map.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl());
        map.enableDoubleClickZoom();
        map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());enter code here
        point = new GLatLng(lat,lang);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.setCenter(point, 17);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
   }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code in from the google maps API v2, which is deprecated.  Any new maps should be implemented with v3.

There are a number of ways to do it, if you are stuck on v2, see [Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/).

I have translated some of his examples to v3, see http://www.geocodezip.com

Comment: Just a quick note, V2 could be shut off as early as next May, so you really shouldn't stay with it.